# Translation of a Fourier Image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, fft

I know that DC component in Frequency Domain is always at F(0,0) i.e at TOP LEFT. If I want to bring it to centre, they say we need to multiply the image, f(x,y), with (-1)^(x+y) and it will take the DC component to centre. I am not able to understand it, how this happens. Also if DC component is brought to the centre then what value has gone to F(0,0)? I read this in Gonzalez, Please explain me with the help of an example so that I can understand it that how F(0,0) is brought to centre and what value moves to F(0,0).

Comment: The Fourier transform is periodic, so the image wraps around at the edges - you can therefore shift the origin however you like, so long as you respect this modulo indexing.

Comment: Thanks Paul but from where can i learn this in detail. Please mention some link.

Comment: It's a big subject area - you should probably start with a couple of good introductory books on DSP and image processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem of understanding until I read this OpenCV tutorial (focus on point 6.): 
**http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html** 
So if you divided your frequency domain image into four quadrants, then:

- Swap top-left quadrant with bottom-right quadrant
- Swap top-right quadrant with bottom-left quadrant